# While saving image in internal storage, a copy of that image is storing in pictures folder named with timestamp

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, save-image

I am storing an image in internal storage. I have a bitmap. but it is also storing a copy of that image in pictures folder named with the time stamp. please help me on that.

```
 private void saveBitmapCropped(Bitmap bitmap,String uid){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file=new File(path+"/.Cropped_images",uid+".jpg");
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    saveRes(String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(file)),"uri");
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Bitmap pictureBitmap = bitmap;
        pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what is the behaviour you're seeing vs what is the behaviour you're expecting to see. Can you clarify?

Comment: If the image came from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, then the camera app decided to save its own copy of the image. That is well within the rights of the developers of that camera app.

Answer (score 0):

I identify the issue, only the issue was with this line.. if you delete this line all the things goes well

```
 MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```